# Get the outlets inside a NSMatrix

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, interface-builder, osx-lion

I have a NSMatrix which contains 5 cells, each cell contains an image well.
I want to avoid binding each image well, so I just have an IBOutlet which is a NSMatrix.How can I take the content of each column (that should be a NSImageWell) from the matrix?
For example I have that matrix:

```
@property (weak) IBOutlet NSMatrix *cells;
```

And the cell at column 1:

```
NSCell* cell=[ cells cellAtRow: 0 column: 0];
// How do I get the contained NSImageWell?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean, each cell contains an image well? How did you make your matrix?  As far as I know, you can't put an image well inside a "cell". If you drag an image well onto your window, and then embed it in a matrix, the cells are NSImageCells, they're not contained in an NSCell. So, this line will get you the image cell:

```
NSImageCell* cell= [cells cellAtRow: 0 column: 0];
```